# How to handle dynamically registered processes and pattern matching in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

When I register a process to an atom, I can send a message via the atom instead of the Pid interchangeably, which is convenient. However, pattern matching seems to treat Pid and atom as different entities, which is expected but inconvenient. In my example, the `{Pid, Response}` pattern does not match since `Pid` in this scope is an atom but the message sent as response contains the actual Pid.

Is there a preferred way to handle this?

The Program:

```erlang
-module(ctemplate).
-compile(export_all).

start(AnAtom, Fun) ->
    Pid = spawn(Fun),
    register(AnAtom, Pid).

rpc(Pid, Request) ->
    Pid ! {self(), Request},
    receive
        {Pid, Response} ->
            Response;
        Any -> 
            io:format("Finish (wrong):~p~n",[{Pid, Any}])
    end.

loop(X) ->
    receive
        {Sender, Any} ->
            io:format("Received: ~p~n",[{Sender, Any}]),
            Sender ! {self(), "Thanks for contacting us"},
            loop(X)
    end.
```

The Shell:

```
Eshell V5.10.2  (abort with ^G)
1> c(ctemplate).
{ok,ctemplate}
2> ctemplate:start(foo, fun() -> ctemplate:loop([]) end).
true
3> ctemplate:rpc(foo, ["bar"]).
Received: {<0.32.0>,["bar"]}
Finish (wrong):{foo,{<0.40.0>,"Thanks for contacting us"}}
ok
4> whereis(foo).
<0.40.0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use references instead. The example you are suggesting is actually one of the reasons why refs are better for synchronous messages. Another reason is that sometimes you cannot guarantee that the received message is the one you are actually expecting.

So, your code will look like something

```
rpc(PidOrName, Request) ->
    Ref = make_ref(),
    PidOrName ! {{self(), Ref}, Request},
    receive
        {{Pid, Ref}, Response} ->
            Response;
        Any ->
            io:format("Finish (wrong):~p~n",[{PidOrName, Any}])
    end.

loop(X) ->
    receive
        {{Pid, Ref}, Any} ->
            io:format("Received: ~p~n",[{Sender, Any}]),
            Sender ! {{self(), Ref}, "Thanks for contacting us"},
    end,
    loop(X).
```

A couple notes about your and my code:

1. Note how I moved the last loop/1 call to the end of the function out of the receive block. Erlang does compile-time tail call optimizations, so your code should be fine, but it's a better idea to make tail calls explicitly – helps you to avoid mistakes.
2. You are probably trying to re-invent `gen_server`. The only two major differences between `gen_server:call/2` and my code above are timeouts (`gen_server` has them) and that the reference is created by monitoring the remote process. This way, if the process dies before the timeout is thrown, we receive an immediate message. It's slower in many cases, but sometimes proves itself useful.

Overall, try to use OTP and read its code. It's good and gives you better ideas of how Erlang application should work.

Comment: Looks good :) I am just starting to fiddle with Erlang and want to understand the core first before looking at OTP. Thanks for pointing me in that direction though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
rpc(Pid, Request) ->
Pid ! {self(), Request},
receive
    {whereis(Pid), Response} ->
        Response;
    Any -> 
        io:format("Finish (wrong):~p~n",[{Pid, Any}])
end.
```

you can this function `whereis()`:

> whereis(RegName) -> pid() | port() | undefined

```
 Types:
 RegName = atom()

Returns the pid or port identifier with the registered name RegName. Returns undefined if the name is not registered.
```

For example:

> whereis(db).
>
> <0.43.0>

Comment: But when I use `whereis`, I *have* to use atoms, right? I was looking for a solution where I can use Pids and atoms interchangeably.

Comment: @eteubert you are right, you need an atums as parameter. I think there is no such function for your propuse.

Comment: After being stumped for a week, I finally diagnosed the problem with my program: `You can't use a registered name in a pattern match`, which means that while you *can* use a registered name to send a message, you can't use a registered name to receive a message.  So then I went searching for confirmation, and I ended up here.  But when I try`whereis(my_server)` in a pattern, I get the error: `illegal pattern`. Erlang/OTP 17.  I have to assign the result of whereis() to a variable, then pattern match with the variable.